# How to create react-app using directly only docker instead of host?

Tags: reactjs, docker, yarnpkg

I am creating new Reactjs application using Docker and I want to create new instance without installing Node.js to host system. I have seen many of tutorials but everytime first step was to install Node.js to the host, init app and then setup Docker. Problem I ran into was the official Node.je Docker images are designed for run application only instead of to run like detached container, so I cannot use container command line to initial install. I was about to create image based on any linux distro and install Node.js on my own, but with these approache I cannot use advantages of prepared official images of Node.js. 
Does exist any option how to init React app using Docker without installing Node.js to the host system? 
Thank You

EDIT: Based od @David Maze answer I decide to use docker-compose, just mount project directory to container and put `command: ["sleep", "infinity"]` to docker-compose file. So I didn't need to install Node.js to host and I can manage everthing from container command line as usual in project folder. I wasn't solving any shared global cache, but I am not really sure that it is needed if I will have more versions of node containered because of conflict of npms of different versions. Maybe I try to mount it like volume to containers from some global place in the host one day, but disk space is not so big problem ...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run something like:

```
sudo docker run \
  --rm \
  -it \
  -u$(id -u):$(id -g) \
  -w/ \
  -v"$PWD":/app \
  node:10 \
  npx create-react-app app
```

You will have to repeat this litany of Docker options every time you want to do anything to use a Docker-packaged version of Node.

Ultimately this sequence of things starts in the container root directory (`-w/`) and uses create-react-app to create an `app` directory; the `-v` option has that backed by the current directory on the host, and the `-u` option is needed to make filesystem permissions line up.  The `-it` options make it possible to answer interactive questions, and `--rm` causes the container to clean up after itself.

I suspect you will find it much easier to just install Node.

Comment: Thank You. No doubt that install Node.js is much easier, but I will probably need more versions of Node.js and isn't purpose of development with Docker get rid of installing dev/run libraries to host?

Comment: I find Docker very useful as a tool to ensure that I can run exactly what I’m deploying to production, without actually deploying it; I haven’t found it effective to replace core development tools or as a packaging mechanism for software that principally needs to deal with local files.

Comment: I use it for every tasks usually (docker-compose), code, lib folders and data folders  in volumes, only IDE on host. It is ompletelly replicable environment from scratch, always same everywhere everytime. I decided to build my own image to replicate server state. 
Thank You very much for explanation